# Who was the first to publish the term 'spacetime'?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, history, specific-reference

I'm looking for the earliest references to the word [*spacetime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) (in the modern sense), in any language.
The first references would likely be in German, as *Raum-zeit* or *Raumzeit*.

Of course, H. Minkowski is credited as the originator of the idea. I found the following references to Minkowski's work in [Pauli's Theory of Relativity](https://archive.org/details/theoryofrelativi00paul/page/20/mode/2up?view=theater):

1. "*Das Relativitätsprinzip*", published twice:

- Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung (Jber. dtsch.
  Mat. Ver.), 24 (1915) 372
- Annalen der Physik (Ann. Phys., Lpz.), 47
  (1915) 972

2. "*Die Grundgleichungen für die elektromagnetischen Vorgänge in bewegten Köpern*", published twice:

- Nachrichten von der Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Göttingen
  (Nachr. Ges. Wiss. Göttingen) (1908) 53
- Mathematische Annalen (Math. Ann.), 68 (1910) 472

3. *Raum und Zeit*, published twice:

- Physikalische Zeitschrift (Phys. Z.), 10 (1909) 104
- Das Relativitätsprinzip (Leipzig 1913) - English translation [here](https://archive.org/details/principleofrelat00lore/page/74/mode/2up?view=theater). **Here he uses *die Welt* ('the world') instead of *Raum-zeit* or *Raumzeit* (space-time)**.

I have only been able to find the text of number 3, in English translation.

Two questions:

- Is there any online access to these old German publications?
- Does anyone know of any early references to publications
  containing the word *Raum-zeit* or *space-time* in the text?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is really a bout [hsm.se]

Comment: Agreed. I didn't know about the History site....I have re-posted the same question in that forum - [https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/15325/]